# BindingResolutionException: Target class [path\to\class] does not exist (Laravel 6)

Tags: php, composer-php, laravel-6

I'm using Laravel 6 and php 7 along with ReactJS. I'm following [Build a Basic CRUD App with Laravel and React](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/12/06/crud-app-laravel-react) tutorial to learn how to make a CRUD app. In the tutorial, it says that I need to enable CORS so the API can be accessed from the front-end application. After I install the barryvdh cors by running:

`composer require barryvdh/laravel-cors`

and add it to my Kernel.php:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        ...
        \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        ...
        \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,
    ],
];
```

the class is still undefined in Laravel and I get the error shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MpOP.png)

Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSilp.png) of my code.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: did you tried to php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Barryvdh\Cors\ServiceProvider" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using an out of date tutorial. If you Google for `barryvdh/laravel-cors`, you'll see that the repository has been renamed to `fruitcake/laravel-cors`.

```
composer require fruitcake/laravel-cors
```

I suspect that the dependency therefore didn't install, or if it did, that you're referencing the incorrect namespace. It should be:

```
\Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class
```